# mscorlib: TypeError: f.apply is not a function

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I am trying to run a nodejs function that creates a SAS Token for IoT Hub. However, upon running the code, the function crashes with the following exception:

```
2016-06-23T19:01:24.415 Exception while executing function: Functions.getSASToken. mscorlib: TypeError: f.apply is not a function
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (C:\Program Files (x86)\SiteExtensions\Functions\0.2.10238\bin\edge\double_edge.js:34:28), <anonymous>:42:7).
```

The function I am trying to run is a SAS token generator published by Microsoft, I have only adjusted it to run for Functions:

```
var crypto = require('crypto');
var util = require('util');

var sbNamespace = process.env.SBNAMESPACE || 'xxx.azure-devices.net';

var generateSasToken = function(resourceUri, signingKey, policyName, expiresInMins) {
    resourceUri = encodeURIComponent(resourceUri.toLowerCase()).toLowerCase();

    // Set expiration in seconds
    var expires = (Date.now() / 1000) + expiresInMins * 60;
    expires = Math.ceil(expires);
    var toSign = resourceUri + '\n' + expires;

    // using crypto
    var decodedPassword = new Buffer(signingKey, 'base64').toString('binary');
    const hmac = crypto.createHmac('sha256', decodedPassword);
    hmac.update(toSign);
    var base64signature = hmac.digest('base64');
    var base64UriEncoded = encodeURIComponent(base64signature);

    // construct autorization string
    var token = "SharedAccessSignature sr=" + resourceUri + "&sig="
    + base64UriEncoded + "&se=" + expires;
    if (policyName) token += "&skn="+policyName;
    // console.log("signature:" + token);
    return token;
};

module.exports.getSASToken = function getSASToken(context, req) { 
    var token = req.query.token;
    var deviceId = req.query.deviceId;
    var resourceUri = util.format('%s/devices/%s', sbNamespace, deviceId);

    var sasToken = generateSasToken(resourceUri, token, null, 14400);

    context.log(sasToken);
    context.send(sasToken);    
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that the Functions is expecting your code to export a single **unnamed** function. So remove the `getSASToken` name and you should be good. I.e., change:

```
module.exports.getSASToken = function getSASToken(context, req) {
    ...
}
```

to

```
module.exports = function getSASToken(context, req) {
    ...
}
```